# Error al ingresar un dato DateTime en Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

Al ingresar los datos en el programa en formato date time para la base de datos, al darle aceptar (imagen 1) [image: imagen1]

me muestra el siguiente error (imagen 2)[image: imagen 2]

```
    public bool insertar(string sql)
        {
            cn.Open();
            comando = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            if (i > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            { return false; }

        }
```

Puse el mismo formato del tiempo a como lo tiene y pide la base de datos (imagen 3).

```
 private void boton_promocion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        fecha_inicio.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        fecha_inicio.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
        fecha_fin.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        fecha_fin.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
        int activo;

        if (radio_promociones.Checked)
        {
            activo = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            activo = 0;
        }

        string registrar_usuario = "insert into tb_promociones(Status, Nombre, Fecha_inicio, Fecha_fin, Descuento, fk_platillos) values ('" + activo + "','" + this.texto_nombrePlatillo.Text + "' , '" + this.fecha_inicio.Text + "','" + this.fecha_fin.Text + "', '" + this.texto_descuento.Text + "', '" + this.combo_platillos.SelectedValue + "')";

        if (obDatos.insertar(registrar_usuario))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Se ha registrado a Promocion Correctamente");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al Insertar, Consulte al Administrador del Sistema");
        }
    }
```

[image: imagen 3]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_promociones] ( [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, [Status] BIT NULL, [Nombre] VARCHAR (50) NULL, [Fecha_inicio] DATETIME NULL, [Fecha_fin] DATETIME NULL, [Descuento] VARCHAR (50) NULL, [fk_platillos] INT NULL, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)

insert into tb_promociones(Status, Nombre, Fecha_inicio, Fecha_fin, Descuento, fk_platillos) values ('1','pollo' , '28/05/2018 02:10:02 a. m.','29/05/2018 02:10:02 a. m.', '20', '')
```

Comment: Hola. Creo que sería de ayuda si mostrases la estructura de la tabla de la base de datos donde quieres guardar esos valores y la parte del código donde declaras las variables fecha_inicio y fecha_fin.

Comment: En vez de poner imágenes de tu código, ponlo en texto para que sea mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_promociones] (
    [Id]           INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Status]       BIT           NULL,
    [Nombre]       VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Fecha_inicio] DATETIME NULL,
    [Fecha_fin]    DATETIME NULL,
    [Descuento]    VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [fk_platillos] INT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)

Comment: insert into tb_promociones(Status, Nombre, Fecha_inicio, Fecha_fin, Descuento, fk_platillos) values ('1','pollo' , '28/05/2018 02:10:02 a. m.','29/05/2018 02:10:02 a. m.', '20', '')

Comment: @ManuelBarba Edita tu pregunta añadiendo ese codigo en ella.

Comment: listo y gracias !

Comment: @ManuelBarba Tambien deberias quitar la imagen del código (la del error no) y añadir el código en la pregunta para que podamos ver todo bien como lo tienes (ya que en la imagen no se aprecia)

Comment: listo ya lo agregue

Comment: @ManuelBarba Te falta poner el código mas importante, el trozo donde recojes los valores de los DateTimePicker y los añades en el Insert

Comment: Para este tipo de cosas suele ir bien definir el campo de base de datos como varchar2(16) y guardar la fecha en formato string, y al recuperarla de base de datos convertirla a datetime

Comment: ya agregue el otro codigo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes es que estas pasando la fecha en un formato incorrecto para la base de datos.

En el `Insert` que nos muestras le estas pasando el formato `'28/05/2018 02:10:02 a. m.'` que no es correcto para la Base de datos.

Recojiendo las fechas de los `DateTimePicker` deberias indicar el formato de inserción a la Base de Datos correcto, por ejemplo `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` y quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
string registrar_usuario = "insert into tb_promociones(Status, Nombre, 
    Fecha_inicio, Fecha_fin, Descuento, fk_platillos) 
    values ('" + activo + "','" + this.texto_nombrePlatillo.Text + "' , '" + 
    this.fecha_inicio.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "','" + 
    this.fecha_fin.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "', '" + 
    this.texto_descuento.Text + "', '" + this.combo_platillos.SelectedValue + "')";
```

Comment: me arroja el siguiente error
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: @ManuelBarba Si te da ese error, revisa en que formato regional tienes la BD, depende del que tengas sera un formato u otro.

Comment: como puedo verlo, y en que region me recomiendas ponerlo?

Comment: @ManuelBarba Puedes ver el formato en la misma BD, que tipo de BD estas usando, SQL Server, MySQL?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server